# How do I use Event Queue requestDelay in ExtJS -4.1

Tags: richfaces, extjs4.1

We are developing ERP with combination of Grails 2.1.x + ExtJS-4.1.x .We are using ExtJS MVC + ExtJS data package. In this situation we need to use event queue to avoiding concurrency problem for event handler/listener. I would like use event queue request delay to ignore dump responses like RichFaces 4.x as following:

```
<a4j:queue requestDelay="500" ignoreDupResponses="true"/>
```

How do could i use RichFaces event queue like features in ExtJS-4.1.x

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on what is your choice of comunication between Ext and your backend, if you're planing to use `Ext.Direct` you can batch the request in almost the same way by using `Ext.direct.RemotingProvider.enableBuffer` with a value of 500 and you'll get "almost" the same result as with: `<a4j:queue requestDelay="500"/>` but for ignoring duplicate requests you have to implement your own queue or, better yet, override `Ext.direct.RemotingProvider` or, if you really want to control everything, you can implement your own provider and, that way, you will have a very fine grained control of requests and responses, check the docs for [RemotingProvider](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.direct.RemotingProvider)